# Check if multiple buttons are released android studio/java

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I want my program to send 0 only if all buttons are released.
The code now sends 0 when i release the button, but if i hold to button and release one of them it will send 0 but i dont want it to do that i only want when all of the button are released.
Thanks.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.commend1B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    commend1BHold = true;
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 1");
                    bluetooth.write("1#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
                    bluetooth.write("0#");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend2B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 2");
                    bluetooth.write("2#");

                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
                    bluetooth.write("0#");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend3B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 3");
                    bluetooth.write("3#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
                    bluetooth.write("0#");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend4B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 4");
                    bluetooth.write("4#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
                    bluetooth.write("0#");
                }
                break;


            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + view.getId());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you release a button (any button), call a method that checks if all the buttons are released. If they are, send `0`.

There is also a possibility to count the pressed buttons: every time you press a button, you increase the counter and vice versa. If the counter is zero, send `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I made Boolean for each button to check if it's pressed or not when I press it will be true and when I release it will turn false. Instead of sending 0 when I release it will check if every button is not pressed (check that all the Boolean are false) and only then send a 0.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.commend1B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    commend1BHold = true;
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 1");
                    bluetooth.write("1#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    commend1BHold = false;
                    send0();

                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend2B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    commend2BHold = true;
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 2");
                    bluetooth.write("2#");

                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    commend2BHold = false;
                    send0();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend3B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    commend3BHold = true;
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 3");
                    bluetooth.write("3#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    commend3BHold = false;
                    send0();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.commend4B:
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                    commend4BHold = true;
                    Log.i("sending", "sending 4");
                    bluetooth.write("4#");
                } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == ACTION_UP){
                    commend4BHold = false;
                    send0();
                }
                break;


            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + view.getId());
        }

        return false;
    }
    public void send0(){
        if(!commend1BHold &&!commend2BHold && !commend3BHold && !commend4BHold){
            Log.i("sending", "sending 0");
            bluetooth.write("0#");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).